# VXML call transfer

Tags: vxml

I wrote an VXML file where first when user entered the system he listens welcome audio source, then he needs to enter a number for transferring call to the number that he entered. If a user does not enter a number so call must be transferred to operator with number 2212. But this vxml does not transfer any call, where I have made mistake and how can I fix it?

```
<vxml version="2.0">

<var name="number"/>    
<form id="main">
    <field name="phone" type="digits?length=4">
        <grammar mode="dtmf" type="application/grammar+regex">[0123456789] </grammar>


        <prompt bargein="false" timeout ="60">
            <audio src="flash:welcome.au"/>
        </prompt>

        <noinput>
            <transfer name="transferToOperator" dest="phone:2212">
        </noinput>

         <nomatch>
            <transfer name="transferToOperator" dest="phone:2212">
        </nomatch>

     <filled>
        <assign name="number" expr="phone"/>
        <transfer name="transferToInputNumber" dest="phone:number">
     </filled>
    </field>

</form>
```

Comment: If the suggested answer isn't right, it might be helpful to know what your platform logs indicate is happening.

Comment: which platform you are using to run vxml?

Answer (score 0):

dest="phone:2212" may be valid for your platform, but the specification says this should be:

> dest  The URI of the destination (telephone, IP telephony address).
>   Platforms must support the tel: URL syntax described in [RFC2806] and
>   may support other URI-based addressing schemes.

So your attribute should be: dest="tel:2212"

Answer (score 0):

You have made use mistake in your application code with wrong use of  tag

See the parent - child relationship of vxml application tag here:
http://help.voxeo.com/go/help/xml.vxml.elements.overview

As per your given application code, you can do like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vxml version="2.0">

<var name="number"/>    
<form id="main">
    <field name="phone" type="digits?length=4">
        <grammar mode="dtmf" type="application/grammar+regex">[0123456789] </grammar>


        <prompt bargein="false" timeout ="60s">
            <audio src="flash:welcome.au"/>
        </prompt>

        <noinput>
            <goto nextitem="transferToOperator"/>
        </noinput>

         <nomatch>
        <goto nextitem="transferToOperator"/>   
        </nomatch>

     <filled>
        <assign name="number" expr="phone"/>
        <goto nextitem="transferToInputNumber"/>
     </filled>
    </field>
    <transfer name="transferToOperator" dest="tel:2212">
    <filled>
        <disconnect/>
       </filled>
    </transfer>
   <transfer name="transferToInputNumber" dest="tel:number">
<filled>
    <disconnect/>
       </filled>
</transfer>
</form>
</vxml>
```